# Помогите сделать функцию с jquery на нативный js

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

> Проблема с
> document.getElementById('smartname').html(decodeURI(getParams['smartname'])

```
if (getParams['smartname']!=undefined && getParams['smartname'].length > 0 && getParams['smartname']!='undefined'){
    console.log(getParams['smartname']);
  document.getElementById('smartname').innerHTML(decodeURI(getParams['smartname'])+ ', ');

};
```

Comment: делайте fiddle так все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById('smartname');
if (el) {
    el.innerHTML = decodeURI(getParams['smartname'])+ ', ';
}
```